# Attach user ID to save/update/create in a clean way in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

So I have a lot of controllers that will be created by one user. So on every save/create/update I want the user's ID to be saved the resource's `user_id` column in the database.

I know that before the actual database update I could go like

```
$resource->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
```

but this seems pretty unclean and I don't wanna do this for all the create/update actions I have spread across multiple controllers.

What would be the best and cleanest way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eloquent ORM to define $resource you can define Events for that model, that will be executed (if you wish) after or before every create, update, save, delete or restore action on that model. You can see the documentation here: [Laravel 5.1 Model Events Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events)

Answer (score 1):

Create a trait that hooks into the model’s saving event, and set the user ID there.